# Dlib and face-recognition libraries installation on windows 11

Tags: python, subprocess, face-recognition, dlib, windows-11

I am unable to install dlib and face-recognition libraries on my pc.(vsCode)I tried the method using cmd. I installed pycharm to give another try but I still struggle

The process recommended to install it is to  install cmake before installing dlib. I installed cmake..when it comes to  dlib this error occurs: subprocess-exited-with-error
pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

The same errors appears concerning the face-recognition library.I am stuck due to the fact that I need them installed to finish my facial recognition program.

Please can you help to install the both libraries or help me to make this program using other equivalent libraries. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.